# Naming files when uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to Amazon S3, nothing special. I have managed to do the actual upload, and the file uploads successfully. The only issue that's left is that I cannot change the name of the file in S3. It seems that by default, the name of the file is being set the same as the secret key. It could be that I am sending the secret key as a parameter where I should send the name of the file instead. However, I tried changing the parameters around and errors prop up.

Below please find the code I am using:

```
Bucket bucket = client.createBucket("testBucket", Region.EU_Ireland);

    List<PartETag> partTags = new ArrayList<>();

    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest request = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(
            bucket.getName(), secretAmazonKey);

    InitiateMultipartUploadResult result = client
            .initiateMultipartUpload(request);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    long contentLength = file.length();
    long partSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024;

    try {
        // Uploading the file, part by part.
        long filePosition = 0;

        for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
            // Last part can be less than 8 MB therefore the partSize needs
            // to be adjusted accordingly
            partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));

            // Creating the request for a part upload
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucket.getName()).withKey(secretAmazonKey)
                    .withUploadId(result.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i)
                    .withFileOffset(filePosition).withFile(file)
                    .withPartSize(partSize);

            // Upload part and add response to the result list.
            partTags.add(client.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());

            filePosition += partSize;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        client.abortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest(bucket
                .getName(), secretAmazonKey, result.getUploadId()));
    }

    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
            bucket.getName(), secretAmazonKey, result.getUploadId(), partTags);

    client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key` in your upload requests is actually your object (file) key (name), and not your AWS secret key. Whenever you instantiate your `client` instance, this is the time where you specify your AWS credentials.

Could you be more specific regarding the errors you are seeing when doing this?

Comment: As you said, I was using the secret key instead of the file key (i.e. file name on S3). Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I used Amazon S3 for the first time recently and was able to upload a file as below:

```
public void saveMinutes(Minutes minutes, byte [] data)
{

  AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonS3AccessKey, amazonS3SecretAccessKey));
  ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
  metaData.setContentLength(data.length);
  metaData.setContentType("application/pdf");
  s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(amazonS3MinutesBucketName, minutes.getFileName(), new ByteArrayInputStream(data), metaData));
}
```